# How to install MySQL in Fedora20?

Tags: mysql, fedora, fedora20

How to install MySQL in Fedora20?

and how to open mysql prompt after installation using guest user.

Answer (score 0):

> How to install MySQL in Fedora20?

Fedora uses the [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/) fork of MySQL. It's a drop in replacement for MySQL.

To install the server package, run the following as root:

```
# yum install mariadb-server
```

To start the server, run the following as root:

```
# systemctl start mysqld.service
```

To enable the server to start on boot, run the following as root:

```
# systemctl enable mysqld.service
```

---

> and how to open mysql prompt after installation using guest user.

This response to the second part of your question, assumes that you have already installed the server package as above, and started it, and want to connect to that server:

First, install the client package. Run the following as root:

```
# yum install mariadb
```

Then run the client (prompt), by invoking the following:

```
$ mysql
```

Comment: Ok devendra, ok let me know if there's any additional info that would make this answer better. Also, don't forget to vote for all of the answers that provided you with useful info, then choose the one that best answers your question as the 'chosen answer'.